# None of the keys entered are valid keys - R

Tags: r, arrays

I am trying to learn how to manipulate microarrays for differential expression analysis. While I am trying to add some annotation I can not find the keytype related to:

```
select(hugene10sttranscriptcluster.db,
       keys = my_keys,
       columns = c("GENENAME", "SYMBOL"),
       keytype = "PROBEID")
-------------------------------------------------------
Error in .testForValidKeys(x, keys, keytype, fks) : 
  None of the keys entered are valid keys for 'PROBEID'. Please use the keys method to see a listing of valid arguments.
```

Being the keys:

```
my_keys
---------------------------------------------------------------------
[1] "16650045" "16650047" "16650049" "16650051" "16650053" "16650055" "16650057" "16650059"
```

I tried every possible type from keytypes(hugene10sttranscriptcluster.db) with no successful result:

```
"16650045" %in% keys(hugene10sttranscriptcluster.db, "GENEID") 
------------------------------------------------------------------
[1] FALSE
```

Is there any documentation/alternative where I can find it. I have been looking through the documentation (Array Express) but did not help me. I am also not sure; is it possible that I require a different package (hugene10sttranscriptcluster.db)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively, I did have a problem with the package. If anyone has the same problem just try to look for the annotation of the microarray in the documentation (pd.hugene.2.0.st in my case) to install and use the proper package (hugene20sttranscriptcluster.db)